# C++ How to have an instance of the same class as an attribute?

Tags: c++, class, reference

I am trying to have a class called Cube have an attribute that is an instance of another cube.

Here are the important parts of my Cube.cpp:

```
bool hasSon = false;
Cube* son;
Cube::Cube()
{
}
void Cube::setSon(Cube* s)
{
    son = s;
    hasSon = true;
}
void Cube::draw() {if(hasSon) {son->draw()}}
```

And here is my cube.h:

```
    class Cube
{
public:
    Cube();
    bool hasSon;
    Cube* son;
    void setSon(Cube* son);
    void draw();
};
```

I am instancing the cube and using setSon(); like so:

```
Cube* base = new Cube();
Cube* base2 = new Cube();
base->setSon(base2);
```

The problem I am getting is that I get memory erros, even if I never call `setSon();` what would be the correct way to set the `son` attribute?

Here is my error:

```
    Exception thrown at 0x00DA3716 in CG_Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDF1.
Unhandled exception at 0x00DA3716 in CG_Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDF1.
```

Comment: How do you use `Cube` and call `setSon`?

Comment: It's imperative that you provide a [mcve]. You're going to have a hard time finding someone who can tell you what's wrong without having enough information.

Comment: @songyuanyao I have added it in an edit.

Comment: @chris what is missing? I just added my console error output

Comment: Do you really have `bool hasSon = false;` and `Cube* son;` at the top of your source file? or is that a typo?

Comment: @MtRoad Yes I do

Comment: I tried a [MCVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QDHpfNKf7IaqxqF6) but can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: What I suspect is that the global declarations at the top of the file are shadowing the class variables, so the draw class will always execute `if(hasSon)` since `hasSon` is being set globally.  The global declarations should be removed, since they're otherwise pointless and possibly causing the problem.  I can't get that to happen on my compiler though.

Comment: @chris, given the number of weird things MSVC++ has given me in the past, little surprises me now about C++ compilers.

Comment: What the MCVE is saying is a _complete_ example. Especially now with the uncertainty of whether shadowing is causing issues here, knowing exactly what minimal code is being run to produce this error is step 1. In addition, using a debugger and sanitizer on that code is step 2. Both provide valuable infomation about where the invalid memory access is happening, what the state of the program is at the time, and other information for finding out what happened and why. Debuggers come with compilers and sanitizers are a compiler flag away on GCC and Clang.

Comment: @MtRoad That was exactly the proble, the class variables were being shadowed, after removing them from my file the problem was solved :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `hasSon`. You can initialize the pointer to `nullptr` and use that to test if a `Cube*` has been set. As your provided code is incomplete its hard to say why you get the error, but this works,

```
class Cube
{
public:
    Cube();
    //bool hasSon;
    Cube* son;
    void setSon(Cube* son);
    void draw();
};

Cube::Cube() : son(nullptr)
{}

void Cube::setSon(Cube* s)
{
    son = s;
}

void Cube::draw() 
{
    if(son) 
        son->draw();
}


int main()
{
    Cube* base = new Cube();
    Cube* base2 = new Cube();
    base->setSon(base2);
    base->draw();
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/6I36SK)